# Get Youtube comments with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, youtube-api

I have a project for a client that will be using a YouTube comment stream as a type of "chat." I am making an authenticated call to YouTube using the GData APIs with the Zend Framework. I am looking for a way to run the script that will pull the comment stream with a refresh button so that the users don't have to refresh the page to see their comment, or any new comments that appear. I believe this can be accomplished with JQuery, but after a bt of searching I haven't really found a good explanation as to how. Here are a few brief snippits of my code to give you some idea of what I am looking at:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);
$_SESSION['yt'] = serialize($yt);

/***************** Adds a comment if applicable *****************/

if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{
$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('QQoFLrZ5C3M');

$newComment = $yt->newCommentEntry();
$newComment->content = $yt->newContent()->setText($_POST['comment']);

// post the comment to the comments feed URL for the video
$commentFeedPostUrl = $videoEntry->getVideoCommentFeedUrl();
$updatedVideoEntry = $yt->insertEntry($newComment, $commentFeedPostUrl,
'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_CommentEntry');
}

                        /****************************************************************/


<div id="coments">

$commentFeed = $yt->getVideoCommentFeed('QQoFLrZ5C3M');

echo '<div id="refresh"><a href="#" style="margin-right: 15px; border: 0;"><img src="../common/img/refresh.png" alt="refresh" border="0" /></a></div>';

foreach ($commentFeed as $commentEntry) {
echo '<div class="comment">';
echo  '<a href="http://youtube.com/user/' . utf8_decode(utf8_encode($commentEntry->author[0]->name->text)) . '" target="_blank" class="youtube_user">' . utf8_decode(utf8_encode($commentEntry->author[0]->name->text)) . '</a><br />';

echo  '<span style="font-size: 14px;">' . utf8_decode(utf8_encode($commentEntry->content->text)) . '</span><br />';

// Format time
$timeAgoObject = new convertToAgo;
$ts = strtotime($commentEntry->updated->text);
$timestamp = ($timeAgoObject -> makeAgo($ts)); // Then convert to ago time

echo  '<div class="yt_timestamp">' . $timestamp  . '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Note that the youtube class is not always new (hence the serialization into a session variable) I just stripped out the if statement for easy reading.

Comment: Please make some more effort in explaining the exact problem you are trying to solve. E.g. fix the title and explain the relation between the question and the code sample. This will make the question and its answers more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example for you to use.  It utilizes the Youtube JSON API somewhat detailed here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Comments_Feeds

Insead of XML I am using JSON.

To get the 'data' of your video with JSON, use `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/YOURVIDEOID/comments`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/A32H2/2/

```
//"The Dark Knight Rises trailer, sweded" comments
//http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrmEyPkgDf8

    <div id="comments"></div>

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KrmEyPkgDf8/comments?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50",  
        //gets the max first 50 results.  To get the 'next' 50, use &start-index=50
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(key, val) {

                comment = $("<div class='comment'></div>");

                author = $("<a target='_blank' class='youtube_user'></a>");
                author.attr("href", "http://youtube.com/user/" + val.author[0].name.$t);
                author.html(val.author[0].name.$t);

                content = $("<div style='font-size: 14px;' class='content'></div>");
                content.html(val.content.$t);

                comment.append(author).append(content);
                $('#comments').append(comment);
            });
        }
    });
```

Also I would recommend changing the title of your question to something more descriptive, such as "Get Youtube comments with jQuery"

Comment: Well, in reference to changing the question title, I also plan to post comments using JQuery too, and my hope was that in the event that someone who read my question was unfamiliar with the GData APIs, they might still be able to point me in the right direction with JQuery. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also - forgive my ignorance here, but how could I bind this to a refresh button? I am assuming it would be an onclick function, but I am really not versed in anything other than PHP honestly. Would you mind holding my hand a bit more?

Comment: Makes sense!  You can post comments using the javascript API as well.  Check out the "Adding a comment" section here.  You would POST to the same url as above, with the content described: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Comments

Comment: $("#refreshbutton").click(function(){ //ajax script goes here});

Comment: Considering that this code uses `gdata`(correct me if I am wrong), does return all the comments of a video (even thousand)? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! This method works only for the first 100 comments. How can I fetch more comments than that?
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/KrmEyPkgDf8/comments?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50&start-index=100 does not fetch any comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basic idea:

1. Present the comment form to the user
2. Use jQuery to hook the form's submit event. ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/))
3. Submit the form via AJAX to your backend script. ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/))
4. Insert the record into your database as normal.
5. Echo the HTML for the new comment.
6. After the request is complete, jQuery will return whatever HTML you've echo'd. All that's left is to prepend/prepend the new HTML to your comment list. ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/))

Comment: Thank you so much for the documentation, this helped tremendously.